# Overwrite input value in form field

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have an "Update Profile" script that retrieves the details of the logged in user in a form input, so they can see what the current values are. Like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value='<?= $row->f_name; ?>' title="enter your first name.">
```

This works. When users navigate to the page they see their first name appear in that input box. When they go to change their name and enter in a new value the form submits but keeps the original value and not the updated one. I assume that is because I am hard-coding a value to it with the `value` attribute.

How can I show the user the value in the input so that if they choose to not edit it, it does submit with the original value and not a blank, but if they do choose to add text to the input box the new string is submitted?

Comment: Well check whether a value for that field was passed when the form is send … and then either output that, or your `$row` value …

Comment: I think even if you hardcoded the value attr you still can get the updated value when form submit. Could you show more about your code/controller? BTW, it is highly recommended to use the standard php tag. <?php echo $row->f_name; ?>

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly:

```
value="<?=set_value('first_name', $first_name)?>"
```

The first parameter is the posted value, the second parameter is the default overridden value.

Answer (score 0):

`if($_GET['first_name']==''){

$first_name= $row->f_name;

}else{

$first_name= $_GET['first_name'];

}`

SQL Query :

`"UPDATE`your_table_name`SET`first_name`= '$first_name' WHERE`blablabla`= '$blablalba';"`

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value='f_name; ?>' title="enter your first name.">
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use placeholder attributes.

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="<?= $row->f_name; ?>">
```